# How to add a delay in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".box02").hide();
                $("#select-02").change(function(){
                    $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                        if($(this).attr("title")=="0b"){
                            $(".box02").hide();
                            $(".none").show();
                        }
                        if($(this).attr("title")=="1b"){
                            $(".box02").hide();
                            $(".1b").show();
                        }
                        if($(this).attr("title")=="2b"){
                            $(".box02").hide();
                            $(".2b").show();
                        }
                    });
                }).change();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

<body>          
    <select name="roomcount" id="select-02">
        <option title="0b">---</option>
        <option title="1b">1</option>
        <option title="2b">2</option>
    </select><br/><br/>

    <p class="current count">
        <b>Content:</b>
        <br/>
        <div class="padding-box">
            <span class="none box02">...</span>
            <span class="1b box02">show content 1 with delay</span>
            <span class="2b box02">show content 2 with delay</span>
        </div>
    </p>
</html>
```

How can I add a delay between a transform of a 'span' to another 'span'? Please only change something in the jquery script, because I am using it on multiple sites and can't easily update them and to just change the code it's easier to change.

An example of this delay is on this page: http://store.apple.com/us/buy-mac/mac-pro?product=ME253LL/A&step=config if you change a radio input there is a small delay before it changes.

Thanks, Sake

Comment: What do you mean delay? There's slideUp/Down, fadeOut/In etc. Just replace `hide()` with `fadeOut()` and `show()` with `fadeIn()` ? If you just need a delay, you can do `$(".none").delay(1000).show(1);`

Comment: Your working demo isn't working.  Error on line 9 in Chrome.

Comment: I didn't like the solutions provided to you in answers. Show and Hide have an optional "options" argument where you can provide a callback once the animation is complete like $('.myElement').show({complete:callBackFunctionToCall}); which can call next instance of your animation, of course it can be decoupled even more nicely, but this is the best direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/), [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) effects. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".box02").hide();
                $("#select-02").change(function(){
                    $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                        if($(this).attr("title")=="0b"){
                            $(".box02").delay(600).fadeOut(400);
                            $(".none").delay(600).fadeIn(400);
                        }
                        if($(this).attr("title")=="1b"){
                            $(".box02").delay(600).fadeOut(400);
                            $(".1b").delay(600).fadeIn(400);
                        }
                        if($(this).attr("title")=="2b"){
                            $(".box02").delay(600).fadeOut(400);
                            $(".2b").delay(600).fadeIn(400);
                        }
                    });
                }).change();
            });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/ENB8J/)**

Answer (score 2):

use `setTimeout()`.

The function accepts a function to be executed and milliseconds to wait for execution

For example, if you want to delay an execution of a function by 5 seconds you can do this:

```
setTimeout(functionName,5000);
```

Also note, 1 second = 1000 milliseconds.

If you don't have a function, you can put your code in a anonymous function.

```
setTimeout(function(){
 //do something here
},5000);
```

Also, there is `delay()` function in jquery, which is used for animation

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".box02").hide();
    $("#select-02").change(function(){
      $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("title")=="0b"){
          $(".box02").delay(100).slideUp(500);
          $(".none").delay(100).slideDown(500);
        }
        if($(this).attr("title")=="1b"){
          $(".box02").delay(100).slideUp(500);
          $(".1b").delay(100).slideDown(500);
         }
        if($(this).attr("title")=="2b"){
          $(".box02").delay(100).slideUp(500);
          $(".2b").delay(100).slideDown(500);
         }
      });
  }).change();
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/BrKLU/3/